# Merging a decrypted search of items within a LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sqlclr

I have the following search query:

```
IQueryable<File> files = GetFiles(f => f.Clients.Any(fc => fc.Contacts.Any(c => c.Companies.Any(x => x.Name.Contains(searchText)))));
```

Unfortunately the search for `Companies.Name` will never work because the `Name` is encrypted.

So I have the following list of decrypted `Companies`. It's a Stored Procedure and it uses SQL CLR to decrypt the `Name` field:

```
List<Company> companies = GetSearchCompanies(searchText).Query.ToList();
```

This list is working fine, it returns a list of companies based on the `searchText`.

My question is whether I can replace the original `files` list of companies in order to be able to search against decrypted `Company` names as well as the other searches against `Contacts`, `Clients`, etc.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var newFiles = from f in files
               join c in companies on f.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
               select new File
               {
                   prop1 = f.prop1,
                   //Assign all your other properties
                   Company = c
               };
```